# Extract git branch name while building C# project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild, csproj

While building the C# project locally/CI server, I wanted to control the NuGet package reference in the ***.csproj*** file. If the developer is building a C# project on github ***master*** branch (locally/CI server) I would like to add RC build NuGet package reference otherwise PRE releases NuGet package reference. How to do this? Can someone please assist me?

Some thoughts like -

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
    <GitBranch>$(GitBranch.Trim())</GitBranch>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>     
      <PackageReference Include="GitInfo" Version="2.2.0" />       
  </ItemGroup>

    <Choose>
        <When Condition="$(GitBranch) == 'master'">
            <ItemGroup>
                <PackageReference Include="Data.Account.Domain.Messaging" Version="1.0.0-rc*" IncludePrerelease="true" />
            </ItemGroup>
        </When>
        <Otherwise>
            <ItemGroup>
                <PackageReference Include="Data.Account.Domain.Messaging" Version="1.0.0-pre*" IncludePrerelease="true" />
            </ItemGroup>
        </Otherwise>
    </Choose>    
</Project>
```

Comment: IMO what you're building locally and what's being built on the CI server should 1:1 be exactly the same. Imagine if the PRE package introduces new functionality which the RC does not support, then you'll get differing behaivour at best and compile errors at worst

Comment: Yeah, I agree. But how can I control the NuGet package references? Can you please throw your thoughts?

Comment: Not completely sure what you're asking, but: you mean something like having a pre-build target which uses the `Exec` task to call `git branch` then store that into a GitBranch property which then gets used to select the reference? Should work as long as it gets called before references get resolved, but might mess up what how Visual Studio shows references.

Comment: @stijn, I am just thinking, instead of using pre-build event, is it possible to direct populate GitBranch property in .csproj file? If yes then how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could read the git branch from the .git/HEAD file. Naive implementation like

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <GitBranch>$([System.IO.File]::ReadAlltext('$(MsBuildThisFileDirectory)\.git\HEAD').Replace('ref: refs/heads/', '').Trim())</GitBranch>
</PropertyGroup>
```

You might want to adjust how you get the path to that file, and perhaps use something more robust (e.g. if you just checkout a random commit in git, the file won't contain a branch name but a commit SHA)

Comment: Thank you @stjin. I verified the value of the $GitBranch prop like -

<Target Name="TestValue" BeforeTargets="PrepareForBuild">
  <Message Text="BranchName - $(GitBranch)">
  </Message>
 </Target>


But unfortunately below condition is not getting satisfied. What is wrong/missing?
 
<Choose>
        <When Condition="$(GitBranch) == 'master'">
            <ItemGroup>
                <PackageReference Include="Data.Account.Domain.Messaging" Version="1.0.0-rc*" IncludePrerelease="true" />
            </ItemGroup>
        </When>
</Choose>

Comment: @sanjaykulkarni see edit: was missing an extra Trim() call because the HEAD file ends with a newline

Comment: Thank you so much for your help @stjin. It's working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use variable **$(GitRoot)** from GitInfo itself to build the path, just a small adaption to the existing code but helped for my case where I had to deal with nested folders.

```
<PropertyGroup>  
    <GitBranch>$([System.IO.File]::ReadAlltext('$(GitRoot)\.git\HEAD').Replace('ref: refs/heads/', '').Trim())</GitBranch>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: If you installed GitInfo, no need to make any code. It sets $(GitBranch) property.